# php mysql case syntax mistake

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, case

Here is part of opencart:

**model/catalog/product.php**

```
if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
  $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
}

$sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

$sort_data = array(
    'pd.name',
    'p.model',
    'p.quantity',
    'p.price',
    'rating',
    'p.sort_order',
    'p.date_added'
);

if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
}
```

I am trying to create "price range" filter. And here is my code:

```
    //Filter products based on slider price range

    if ((isset($this->request->get['lower']))&&(isset($this->request->get['higher'])))
    {
    $sql .=  " AND p.price >='". $this->request->get['lower'] ." ' AND p.price <='". $this->request->get['higher'] ."'" ;
    }

    //Filter products based on price slider

if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
    $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
}

$sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

$sort_data = array(
    'pd.name',
    'p.model',
    'p.quantity',
    'p.price',
    'rating',
    'p.sort_order',
    'p.date_added'
);

if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
}
```

It works! But it doesn't work when products have special price from our store. So I'm trying to copy some code from `SORT BY PRICE`. I copied this SQL:

```
(CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)
```

to my custom code:

```
    //Filter products based on slider price range

    if ((isset($this->request->get['lower']))&&(isset($this->request->get['higher'])))
    {
    $sql .=  " AND (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) >='". $this->request->get['lower'] ." ' AND (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) <='". $this->request->get['higher'] ."'" ;
    }

    //Filter products based on price slider
```

But still doesn't work. I get this error:

> Notice: Error: Unknown column 'special' in 'where clause'
>   Error No: 1054

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you don't have a column by that name

Comment: So do you have that column named `special` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the troubleshooting steps that I'd take:

1. Make sure that `special` is included in your SELECT clause
2. Make sure you don't need to use a table prefix such as `p`
3. Numbers probably shouldn't be quoted when doing the SQL comparison

The CASE expression appears to be formatted correctly, so I don't think the expression is the problem.

IMPORTANT: I would highly recommend that you never, ever use the code above in a production environment. You're wide open for SQL injections by taking unfiltered/validated/escaped GET parameters and adding them to a query string.

Answer (score 0):

Check "special" column exists in your table's column list. 
or use the alias before column name (p.special).

Check both options.